# Closing multiple windows quickly from the Win7 taskbar flyout

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I'm using Windows 7's "combine [buttons] when taskbar is full" option, so programs I'm running might each have only one button on the taskbar even when they have multiple windows open. Hovering over one of those buttons brings up a flyout menu that lists the program's windows. Here's an example using MS Outlook:

[image]

I like the fact that I can close windows directly from the flyout by using the little red X button that appears by the window preview on hover (for an example, see the second item in the flyout above).

However, once I close one window, the flyout disappears, and I have to open it again if I want to close another window. How can I make the flyout remain active after I close one of the windows it contains, so that I can quickly close several windows in a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking here. I use Windows 7 64-bit, and have selected the exact same "combine when taskbar is full" option. From the previews pane that pops up on mouseover, I can click multiple red X buttons to close multiple windows, as long as I don't move the cursor out of the preview area. The pane allows for multiple window closing unless you move the mouse somewhere else, say if a window pops up a save dialog.

Comment: I just tried it again, and the pane definitely disappears as soon as I click. Apparently it has the same behavior even when windows aren't collapsed into one taskbar button, though that's probably not relevant to this question.

Comment: @LordTorgamus: Are you testing only with Outlook? Can you just press Win+E a few times to display multiple Explorer windows, then try with those? Also, test using one of the default Aero themes, and with "Adjust for best performance" selected in the Performance Options dialog (Start / Run / Type "appearance" / Select "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows").

Oh and remember, if you close the right or left-most windows from the preview pane, the pane's sure to resize and close because it's no longer big enough to fit under your cursor.

Comment: How about that? It _was_ Outlook-specific. I tried your Explorer test and got the same results as you, even without with any theme twiddling. Closing the right-most window wasn't a problem, either, as long as I moved my mouse to the left within a few seconds of clicking the close button.

Comment: Trust the Office guys to *always* ignore MS' own usability and UI guidelines and do things the way they please.